# importing sklearn into python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am going through an [awesome tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ONBVNm3isI) in order to learn the [scikit library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for python; however, I am stuck because I am unable to run this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

[image]

I am able to import the library this way:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the version of `scikit-learn` that you're using is too old (check it via `sklearn.__version__`). The function `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split` is introduced since version 0.11.X.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on @YS-L's answer since I don't have enough rep so I will just add to it here:

`train_test_split` should be a defined function inside `cross_validation.py`. You can find the directory in question using `sklearn.__file__` after importing it. If it's not being imported you'll need to update sklearn.